# how can i add footer in downloaded pdf from react component using kendo ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

My requirement is to download a pdf from React component with footer, but how can I add a footer in pdf using PDFExport in Kendo UI?

I am using `PDFExport` in my React component, so I get a pdf on download click, but the requirement is to download the pdf with a footer.

Please help, to Kendo Ui supporter.

```html
<PDFExport
          ref={component => (this.pdfExportComponent = component)}
          scale={0.6}
          fileName={`${selectedBusinessName}DataMap`}
          margin="2cm"
        >
          <div style={{ width: '385mm' }}>
            <h2 style={{ textAlign: 'start' }}>
              {selectedBusinessName.toUpperCase()}
            </h2>
            <h4 style={{ marginTop: '-20px', textAlign: 'start' }}>
              {TotalProcesses} processes flow, {TotalProcessesCategory} data
              categories, {TotalProcessesSystem} systems.
            </h4>
            <div>
              <div className="chart-header">
                <p style={{ marginLeft: '30px', color: '#cc9933' }}>
                  PROCESSES
                </p>
                <p style={{ color: '#cc9933' }}>DATA OBJECTS</p>
                <p style={{ marginRight: '49%', color: '#cc9933' }}>SYSTEMS</p>
              </div>
              {processesByFunction &&
                processesByFunction.map(itm => (
                  <StyleRoot key={`mykey${itm.id}`}>
                    <div className="chart-view-modal" key={`mykey${itm.id}`}>
                      <p
                        className="procees-name"
                        key={`mykey${itm.id}`}
                        style={styles.bounce}
                      >
                        {itm.name.toUpperCase()}
                      </p>
                      <span
                        className="chart-line-view-modal"
                        style={stylesArrow.bounce}
                      />
                      <p className="procees-category" style={stylesCat.bounce}>
                        {itm.category_id.map((item, key) => (
                          <span key={item.value}>
                            {item.label.toUpperCase()}
                            {key < itm.category_id.length - 1 ? (
                              <span> , </span>
                            ) : (
                              ''
                            )}
                          </span>
                        ))}
                      </p>
                      <span
                        className="chart-arrow-view-modal"
                        style={styles3.bounce}
                      >
                        <img src={RightArrow} alt="right-arrow" />
                      </span>
                      <div
                        className="chart-system-block"
                        style={stylesSys.bounce}
                      >
                        {itm.system_id.map((item, key) => (
                          <Fragment key={`mykey${item.value}`}>
                            <p className="procees-system">
                              {item.label.toUpperCase()}
                            </p>
                            {key < itm.system_id.length - 1 ? (
                              <span className="chart-arrow-view-modal-sys">
                                <img src={RightArrow} alt="right-arrow" />
                              </span>
                            ) : (
                              ''
                            )}
                            {/*{key < itm.system_id.length - 1 ? (*/}
                            {/*  <i*/}
                            {/*    className="fa fa-arrow-right"*/}
                            {/*    style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}*/}
                            {/*  />*/}
                            {/*) : (*/}
                            {/*  ''*/}
                            {/*)}*/}
                          </Fragment>
                        ))}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </StyleRoot>
                ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </PDFExport>
```

## reactJS #kendoUI #javascript

Comment: Welcome to SO @Sanjay. Please edit your post to make the question clearer to those that wish to answer it.

Comment: Do you have to edit the pdf?

Comment: yes when pdf download from my pc it'll have footer also in every page

Answer (score 0):

Use Page Template provided by the Kendo UI,

Please find below example for the same.  ( which includes header )
[Example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/pdf-export/page-template/)

Comment: Please consider adding a sample code here along with the external links.
"Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline." Read More at : [answer]